# spanning tree of a DAG (directed acyclic graph) with less forward arcs

Tags: spanning-trees, dag

I am new to this algorithm and graphs. Just started learning. Could someone help me which algorithm is best suited to find the spanning tree of a Directed Acyclic Graph with less forward edges?

Comment: Isn't a Directed Acyclic Graph already a spanning tree?

Comment: @ShubhamSinghrawat : ​ ​ ​ It doesn't need to be. ​ Consider a diamond with all edges directed down. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: What do you mean by "with less forward arc/edges"?

Comment: Probably transitive reduction.